# Restricting ManipulationDelta two-finger touch

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

In WPF, I have a grid that contains a piece of content that I need to manipulate using two-finger touch gestures. The code below works fine for movement and zoom, but I need to know how to restrict the Maximum and Minimum zoom values--for example, 100% to 200% zoom. Also, I need to restrict the movement of the content so it remains within the size of the grid container.

Code so far:

```vb
Private Sub gridLeft_ManipulationStarting(sender As Object, e As ManipulationStartingEventArgs) Handles gridLeft.ManipulationStarting

  e.ManipulationContainer = gridMapHolderLeft
  e.Mode = ManipulationModes.Scale + ManipulationModes.Translate
  e.Handled = True
  MyBase.OnManipulationStarting(e)
End Sub

Private Sub gridLeft_ManipulationDelta(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaEventArgs) Handles gridLeft.ManipulationDelta

  Dim element As UIElement = TryCast(e.Source, UIElement)
  Dim xform As MatrixTransform = TryCast(element.RenderTransform, MatrixTransform)
  Dim matrix As Matrix = xform.Matrix
  Dim delta As ManipulationDelta = e.DeltaManipulation
  Dim center As Point = e.ManipulationOrigin
  matrix.Translate(-center.X, -center.Y)
  matrix.Scale(delta.Scale.X, delta.Scale.Y)
  matrix.Translate(center.X, center.Y)
  matrix.Translate(delta.Translation.X, delta.Translation.Y)
  xform.Matrix = matrix
  e.Handled = True
  MyBase.OnManipulationDelta(e)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the scale by inspecting the resulting matrix.Determinant value AFTER you've applied your scaling. If the value is higher than your maximum, or lower than your minimum scale values, you can simply return from the Sub before you apply the matrix.

In this example, the minimum is no scaling (1.0), and the maximum is 2x scale (2.0).

(Please excuse my VB code - I'm a C# developer 99.9% of the time!)

```
Private Sub gridLeft_ManipulationDelta(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaEventArgs) Handles gridLeft.ManipulationDelta

  Dim element As UIElement = TryCast(e.Source, UIElement)
  Dim xform As MatrixTransform = TryCast(element.RenderTransform, MatrixTransform)
  Dim matrix As Matrix = xform.Matrix
  Dim delta As ManipulationDelta = e.DeltaManipulation
  Dim center As Point = e.ManipulationOrigin
  matrix.Translate(-center.X, -center.Y)
  matrix.Scale(delta.Scale.X, delta.Scale.Y)
  matrix.Translate(center.X, center.Y)
  matrix.Translate(delta.Translation.X, delta.Translation.Y)

  If matrix.Determinant >= 2.0 Or matrix.Determinant <= 1.0 Then
     Return
  End If

  xform.Matrix = matrix
  e.Handled = True
  MyBase.OnManipulationDelta(e)

End Sub
```

I'm mid way through refactoring [a WPF behaviour that provides just these features](https://multitouchtransformbehavior.codeplex.com/). It's written in C#, not VB - but looking at the source-code may be of interest to you. In particular, [the code in the 'ManipulationDeltaHandler' method](https://multitouchtransformbehavior.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trenouth.WPF/Trenouth.WPF.Behaviors/MultitouchTransformBehavior.cs).

There's also code in there to check the bounds of the scaled element against it's container element, to prevent you pushing or scaling stuff out of view.

I ended up writing this behaviour, as the TranslateZoomRotateBehavior provided by Microsoft just doesn't do what we needed to.

I hope there's something in there that helps.

Comment: Thanks very much Olitee, that's really helped